# Having trouble counting iterations of different outputs in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, count, iteration

Trying to set up code to take inputted numbers, determine whether they are negative or positive, displaying this, and then when 0 is put in the code displays the amount of positive numbers put in and the amount of negative numbers put in and then terminates. Having trouble with the counting part and I am not sure how to set this up better. I am also not sure how to set this up to terminate after 0 is put in.

```
function mapping() {
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var countp = 0;
    var countn = 0;

    if (num !== 0) {
        if (num > 0) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "positive";
            countp += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "negative";
            countn += 1;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "countp: " + countp;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "countn: " + countn;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: where are loops?

Comment: -There is lacking information. Do you want the user to input the number and then click button to run this process? 
-First of all you should take out of the function those count variables. If the function runs everytime you evaluate a number, then everytime you do it you are reseting the counters to zero. the inizialization to the variables must run only once

Comment: There should be some user gesture, like clicking a button, or changing input text, then you can run your code after that.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with the code.

- 1st: You need to move `countp` and `countn` outside of the function to make them global.
- 2nd: You are writing the positive number counts to output's html and then you are overriding it by negative count.

This should do the trick;

```js
var countp = 0;
var countn = 0;

function mapping() {
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);

    if (num !== 0) {
        if (num > 0) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "positive";
            countp += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "negative";
            countn += 1;
        }
    } else {
        var html =  "countp: " + countp + ", countn: " + countn;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;

        // this line added
        countp = 0, countn = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<button onclick="mapping()">Test</button>

<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have this linked to an HTML so their is already a button. Would you happen to know how I can make the loop reset/terminate if 0 is entered.

Comment: There is no loop in this code, do you want to reset counters after 0 is entered?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the code is that `countp` and `countn` are local variables. Thus they are created and initialized to `0` every time the function is called. Move the two lines outside the function to fix this bug!

Another bug is the code in the last `else` part. There you *set* `innerHTML` twice, so the div ends up with only `countn`. To fix this bug, replace the last `innerHTML =` by `innerHTML +=`.

Finally, if I understand you correctly, you want that no more updates occur once 0 has been entered. To achieve this, you could add another variable like `isFinal` that is set to `true` when the user enters 0, and add a check to your function.

Some more suggestions:

- Instead of `if (num!==0)`, it is considered good practice to start with positive conditions such as `if (num === 0)`. That way, you will also avoid some nesting in the conditions.
- What happens if the user does not enter a valid number? In your code, this will be treated as negative number. Add a test for "NaN" to fix this.
- You repeat the `document.getElementById...` many times. Use a temporary variable to fix this.
- In modern JavaScript, it is recommended to use `let` or `const` instead of `var`.
- Be consistent in your use of semicolons at the end of lines.

Thus the code ends up as:

```
let countp = 0;
let countn = 0;
let isFinal = false;

function mapping() {
    if (isFinal) {
        return;
    }

    const num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);

    let html = "";

    if (Number.isNaN(num)) {
        html = "invalid";
    } else if (num === 0) {
        html = "countp: " + countp + "<br>";
        html += "countn: " + countn;
        isFinal = true;
    } else if (num > 0) {
        html = "positive";
        countp += 1;
    } else {
        html = "negative";
        countn += 1;
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
}
```